Context Menu Add-in Command(Word) [ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu"]
I am using this example from the Microsoft Docs to add a button in the context menu, I am running the validator and the manifest file is valid. This ExtensionPoint is right below the PrimaryCommandSurface ExtensionPoint.When I add the ContextMenu ExtensionPoint, the Add-in is no longer visible in "My Add-ins", if I remove everything in the Control(inside OfficeMenu) then it appears again. Has anyone run into this issue?
p.s: In my example all the resid-s are mapped correctly to the resources declared Inside Resources.
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
                    <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button2Id1">
                            <Label resid="residLabel2" />
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="residLabel" />
                                <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon2_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon2_32x32" />
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon2_32x32" />
                            </Icon>
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                            </Action>
                        </Control>
                    </OfficeMenu>
                </ExtensionPoint>


I deleted my answer because I can reproduce your problem. There is an inconsistency between the manifest schema and the manifest documentation. I'm looking into that.

Take a look at Greg Maxey's page on modifying the context menu: http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html  See also this archive of Ron deBruin's page: https://web.archive.org/web/20130422140214/http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win014.htm

The documentation has been fixed.

I found this approach which solved my issue:
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
                    <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
                        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ContextMenuButton">
                            <Label resid="ContextMenu.Label"/>
                            <Supertip>
                                <Title resid="ContextMenu.Label"/>
                                <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                            </Supertip>
                            <Icon>
                                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                            </Icon>
                            <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane"<TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId> <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" /></Action>
                        </Control>
                    </OfficeMenu>
                </ExtensionPoint>


I found that it works with <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane"<TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId> <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" /></Action> too.

Yes, we should use the showtaskpane action instead of execute function, I forgot to edit that part.
